# PFSense / Snort / OpenVPN - one WAN interface

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, wide-area-network, snort

I have a pfsense box running both Snort and OpenVPN. The VPN worked great before installing Snort, now intermittently I cannot connect.

Should I whitelist the port that the VPN uses on the WAN interface?

Any comments on the configuration above? I am learning here so your input is valuable.

Comment: You will need to provide more information on your current setup? (E.g. How is the VPN Used & Setup...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some overzealous signatures Snort enables by default that are probably blocking it. Check which is getting triggered. They're probably one(s) you want disabled anyway.